# jQueryUI 1.11 multiple modal dialogs not working

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog

There seem to be an issue with the last version of jQueryUI (1.11) when it comes to using several modal dialogs.

What I am trying to achieve is the following: I have two modal dialogs, the first one contains a button which should open the second dialog:

**HTML**

```
<div id="test1">
    Test 1
    <button id="open_test2">Open Test 2</button>
</div>

<div id="test2">
    Test 2
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    $('#test1').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true
    });
    $('#test2').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        position: {
            my: "right top", at: "right top", of: window
        }
    });

    $('#open_test2').click(function() {
        $('#test2').dialog('open');
    });
})
```

Once the second dialog is opened, I am still able to click on the first dialog !

Here is a link to a fiddle that shows what I am trying to achieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/JC4t5/1/

Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

Comment: Have you read the [1.11 upgrade guide](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.11/)? You may have to use the newly introduced [appendTo](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo) option.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I still am able to see the issue regardless of the update. Could you help by changing the fiddle in the OP and update in comments on how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed with the jQuery UI 1.11.2 release.